# How to Test and Login into PayPal using jMeter?

Tags: java, paypal, jmeter

We had written code using selenium for testing the PayPal login and tried to call the JAR from jMeter. We couldn't get any solution, but instead we're stuck with the errors. Can any one please provide how to Test the PayPal login using jMeter directly ?

Answer (score 1):

There are at least 2 possibilities on how you can use Selenium from JMeter:

1. Drop your JAR to JMeter classpath along with Selenium JARS and their dependencies and invoke your test entry point from [Beanshell](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Sampler) or [JSR223](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) Sampler.
2. Use [JMeter's WebDriver Sampler](http://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler) available via [plugin](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSet/)

Alternatively you can record your PayPal login using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf) and get rid of Selenium bit.